# Send AWS new feature announcement to Slack channel

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to send the aws new featured announcement from https://aws.amazon.com/new to a channel in Slack.
I couldn't find any source in google. Is there anyone who knows how that can be done?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but there's a great newsletter called [Last Week in AWS](https://www.lastweekinaws.com/) you might enjoy.

Comment: This site is also used for such questions when I checked the question's lists and people are willing to help each other by providing useful answers. an example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146706/slack-url-to-open-a-channel-from-browser and there are more... why should this be on hold?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an rss feed for these new features, add the RSS feed module to slack, and subscribe.

https://get.slack.help/hc/en-gb/articles/218688467-Add-RSS-feeds-to-Slack

[AWS new feature RSS feed](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/recent/feed/)

Comment: Thanks for a good reply, I did it and it is working fine.